# Registo (Log) de visitas a um Website através do IP e guradar numa BD

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, ip

Depois de uma pesquisa ainda não encontrei o que queria. Gostava de saber se vocês me conseguem ajudar no raciocínio para esta funcionalidade.
Com PHP e MySql é possível guardar as visitas um Website numa base de dados, e nesta, guardar o IP de quem acedeu à página?
Isto sem cookies, tokens ou logins (forçados) na página.

Cumps.

Comment: problema é que não da pra saber qual o IP real do usuário

Comment: Hum... ok, obrigado. Isto era para ter mais um método de segurança... ou seja, se alguém tentasse aceder, eu saberia sempre.